# No resource found that matches the given name in Android Manifest File

Tags: android

I am android newbie, please help,

> Error:(36, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/FullscreenTheme').

Error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '
>   C:\Users\jrdev_r1m3g5m\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.blwsocietyuk.com.blwsocietyuk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.blwsocietyuk.com.blwsocietyuk.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.blwsocietyuk.com.blwsocietyuk.SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.blwsocietyuk.com.blwsocietyuk.TrendingPosts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_trending_posts"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.blwsocietyuk.com.blwsocietyuk.Webview" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So I have added my style here

```
 <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myTextPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item>

    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <!--<style name="AppThemeBar" parent="AppTheme">-->
    <!--</style>-->

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CardActionButton">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/card_button</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">start|center</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16.0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">4.0dip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="listTitle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>

    <style name="listStyle">
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="listStyleNoHighlight">
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: Did you create a style named "FullscreenTheme"? Show us your styles.xml.

Comment: Have you declared such theme @style/FullscreenTheme' in styles ?

Comment: copy paste your style.xml here under drawable/values folder... Or you can delete android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" to make it work

Comment: Try to use :  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  instead of  android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"

Comment: so I tried delete but it automatically regenerates at build

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand how Styles will work in android
follow below link to get an idea of the same 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

You have defined android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" which is not present in res/values/styles.xml

Comment: Where you seen style.xml ?

Comment: res/values/styles.xml